# Cons of using a hosted SharePoint solution

Tags: 2007, hosting

We possibly are going to be implementing SharePoint into our organization of 5000+ users. Because of political reasons we are being pushed into using a hosted solution on a shared farm with other organizations.

I can already imagine the problems that could occur. Biggest one is not having access to Central Administration and not being able to develop/implement custom solutions.

They only have 3-4 people managing the SharePoint farm and so their response times are sometimes several days.

Because of their "security" they don't even allow SharePoint to access our Active Directory (even though we are both state agencies literally a block away from each other) and I have to send them profile information manually for them to input manually which they have already introduced errors and don't enter in all of the information.

What are some other issues that we might be looking at? Problems with stability? Backup problems?

Comment: @Brian: You may also want to check the other couple of questions on the `hosting` tag: http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hosting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am surprised that 5,000 seats are sitting on a shared hosted environment.
With that many seats, Fpweb.net would recommend a dedicated environment for stability, customization, AD integration and managed service reasons.

We have SharePoint 2010 readily available for SMB and Enterprise customers in both flavors, Foundation and SharePoint Server 2010.

If I can help in any way, let me know.  Hosted SharePoint done right is a viable option for most businesses today.

Regards,
Rob LaMear, MCSE
Found and CEO
Fpweb.net - SharePoint Hosting Pioneer

Comment: @Rob: Thanks for the info. I agree that if it is a hosted environment that it should be a dedicated environment, but they literally have 3-4 people supporting SharePoint, and if they are going to get new equipment...then we would have to pay for it. And due to their nature of support, or lack thereof, and their security issues it seems that if we host ourselves, it would be a better option.

But concerning your hosting solution, which I can't dictate at all if we can host offsite, but I'm curious if we would have access to Central Administration?

Answer (score 1):

I would say the main issue would be that you can't deploy custom code as you've already stated. There is a lot you can achieve by writing javascript/silverlight solutions that talk to the SharePoint web services though.

I would say stability/performance would actually increase as there is no custom code on that environment. Instability is often caused by poorly written custom code.

Backup problems? I don't see why. As long these guys know how to backup/restore SharePoint sites you should be fine.

Comment: I have read of the many things that you can acheive, but I know already from our pilot many things that don't work. None of the audit reports will open, using MySites I get a 403 error trying to add my calendar, without a tool like DeliverPoint user security auditing will be a nightmare, without pulling AD info and synching organization data is going to be out of date along with security settings. It just seems that they 3 guys they have supporting it don't know what they are doing. Better to setup ourselves?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct to be concerned about the viability of a hosted SharePoint solution.  If you're looking for a SharePoint solution which would allow you to benefit from the cost savings and simplicity of the cloud, BUT which at the same time would not bring along the baggage of the cloud such as loss of admin control, restrictions on custom apps, long support response times, uncertain SLA's, etc., then you might want to consider the unique Azaleos Managed SharePoint solution.  You can create a private cloud for your SharePoint farms which is fully customized to your needs.  Azaleos would then take over the full administration headache of the system for you.

Scott Gode, VP  Products, Azaleos